# Excluding objects from Django queryset based on recency

Tags: django, performance, django-models, django-queryset

I have a reddit-like Django app where users can post interesting urls (links) and then publicly comment under them. The two data models to represent this are:

```
class Link(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField(validators=[MaxLengthValidator(500)])
    submitter = models.ForeignKey(User)
    submitted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Publicreply(models.Model):
    submitted_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    answer_to = models.ForeignKey(Link)
    submitted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    description = models.TextField(validators=[MaxLengthValidator(250)])
```

How do I query for all `Links` which have at least 1 or more `publicreply`, and secondly where the latest `publicreply` is **not** by `self.request.user`? I sense something like the following:

```
Link.objects.filter(publicreply__isnull=False).exclude(**something here**)
```

Please advise! Performance is key too, hence the simpler the better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For performance and simplicity you could cache both the number of replies and the latest reply:

```
class Link(models.Model):
    ...
    number_of_replies = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    latest_reply = models.ForeignKey('myapp.Publicreply', related_name='+', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

When a reply is entered, update the corresponding `link.number_of_replies` and `link.latest_reply`.

The query would then be:

```
Link.objects.filter(number_of_replies__gte=1)\
            .exclude(latest_reply__user=request.user)
```